# Should I use multiple constructors or an interface?

Tags: c#, constructor, interface

I have a class called `Package`, in this class I have around 10 attributes, let's call them 1,2,3,4.. etc to 10. The types of these attributes are `strings`, `ints` and some `DateTimes`. When making a new object of Package sometimes I just need attribute 1, sometimes I need 5, 6 and 9, and sometimes I need 3 and 10 etc.

So just two examples: `new Package("bla", "bla bla",100)` or `new Package(2983)`

I've [read](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson13):

> An interface looks like a class, but has no implementation. The only
>   thing it contains are declarations of events, indexers, methods and/or
>   properties. The reason interfaces only provide declarations is because
>   they are inherited by classes and structs, which must provide an
>   implementation for each interface member declared.

Since there are no other methods in the class and just a constructor and attributes, is it better to use like 20 constructors or should I make an interface for this situation?

**EDIT:**
I should've probably mentioned that I also have some `enums` to 'kind of' determine what kind of `Package` it is.

Comment: need, as in you want to fill only those attributes or the object will have only those attributes?

Comment: If u give the class properties with getters/setters and without a constructor  you can do `Package p = new Package() p.YourField = ...` or use multiple constructors

Comment: What do you think an interface would do for you here? As for constructors,  might you have any that have matching signatures? e.g `Package(int, int)` conflicting with `Package(int, int)`?

Comment: @Nikita both actually

Comment: @Sybren I didn't think of that, thats a nice solution

Comment: That all sounds horribly wrong, never create a God Object.  You don't even know what kind of package you got after you created one.  Consider a base class that only stores the package type, derived classes that represent a specific package flavor.

Comment: @DavidG I don't know, maybe there was a solution with this

Comment: Can't you just create multiple classes, one per use case?

Comment: @DavidG yes I could but I would need a lot of classes (around 20) for each case, I was just wondering if there was a better solution for this

Comment: What do you want to happen when I look at Field3 of an instance that does not have a value for that Field?

Comment: @Taemyr It probably wont happen in my case, but it should set it to `null` or something

Comment: @Denny Why will that probably not happen?  Ie. how does the external object now that Field3 is not interesting?

Comment: @Taemyr I've edited my question and I should've mentioned it at the time when I posted this question, but I have a enum attribute which kind of determines what kind of Package it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interface doesn't help you in any way here.

If you want to force that specific variables are filled in together, like 1, 2 and 3 should always be filled together but in another case just 4 is enough, you could use separate constructors, or static methods with helpful names that create the objects (like `CreateFromId`, `CreateFromNameAndAge`).

If you don't care at all, you can simply make a parameterless constructor (or a constructor with optional fields) and set the fields required with object initializers:

```
var x = new Class() { Field1 = 1, Field2 = "2" };
```

Maybe this is a sign you are doing too much in a single object, but without actual information about your class design, we can't tell that much.

Inheritance seems to be a decent solution here too, if the packages have distinct uses (like `ProductPackage`, `PersonPackage`, etc.). The shared properties reside in the base class, and all specific properties can reside in the deriving classes.

Comment: Does this require public setters for the Fields?

Comment: Yes, it does @Taemyr. That might be okay in the user specific case.

Comment: Could you get around that requirement with optional arguments on the constructor?

Comment: Yes (added), but that often makes it very ambiguous what is actually happening and can break your code if you happen to insert another variable.

Comment: I've marked this as the best solution for my situation, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Constructors provide guidelines as to how can an object be created. Assuming that by using an interface you mean specify the properties which need to exist, you are not giving any guidelines as to how properties need to be initialized.

Having multiple constructors should be better since you are providing means in which users can instantiate your objects. This will allow you to initialize your other parameters accordingly.

You could still use an interface if you require to stipulate what fields need to exist.

Answer (score 0):

Besides above points, consider using Builder pattern - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Here is the example:

```
class Package
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }

    public static PackageBuilder Create()
    {
        return  new PackageBuilder(new Package());
    }
}

class PackageBuilder
{
    private readonly Package _package;

    public PackageBuilder(Package package)
    {
        _package = package;
    }

    public PackageBuilder WithName(string name)
    {
        _package.Name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public PackageBuilder WithDescription(string description)
    {
        _package.Description = description;
        return this;
    }

    public PackageBuilder Prop1(string prop)
    {
        _package.Prop1 = prop;
        return this;
    }

    public PackageBuilder Prop2(string prop)
    {
        _package.Prop2 = prop;
        return this;
    }

    public static implicit operator Package(PackageBuilder pb)
    {
        return pb._package;
    }
}

class Client
{
    Package BuildPackage()
    {
        var package =
            Package.Create().WithName("My Package").WithDescription("Description").Prop1("foo").Prop2("bar");
        return package;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't the one to downvote, but your answer could be considered a link-only answer.  It would be better received if you provided a code example based on the information in the question, see [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on the help page.  The builder pattern is probably a good answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this answer needs more information as to how it would fit the question.

Comment: Also not the downvoter, but I've upvoted it since this is also a good solution now I've seen an example how it works. But since Patricks answer was 'easier' and also fits my needs I marked his comment as answer. Thanks!